# Algorithm to multiply 64-bit numbers using 32-bit unsigned integers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, multiplication

I have 64-bit numbers (63 bits + sign bit), represented as two's complement numbers, stored in two unsigned 32-bit integers.

```
struct Long
{
    uint32 high;
    uint32 low;
}
```

How can I implement a multiplication algorithm, using just 32-bit numbers, and check that the result fits in 63-bits? I want to return an error code indicating overflow if the result doesn't fit.

Comment: Most compilers have a long long type which is 64 bits and should work with multiplication.

Comment: I need the algorithm, assuming there isn't 64 bit support.

Comment: Wikipedia describes the algorithms that computers use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier

Comment: It's funny you should ask this, I've been implementing exactly this algorithm today. I am using in-line assembler (in g++ for Intel IA-32), which may not be appropriate for you -- what are your OS and compiler?

Comment: I cannot use assembler, the algorithm need to be portable to other languages, that don't allow assembler, i have try to adapt the long_multiplication algorithm described in http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs301/notes/Chapter5/node5.html, but i cannot get it working

Comment: What do you mean by "no 64-bit support" here? No 32x32→64 bit multiplication? All current architectures have expanding multiplication. That means on 32-bit system you'll have instructions for multiplying two 32-bit numbers and output a 64-bit number, on 16-bit systems you'll have 16x16→32 bit multiplication

Comment: In that case just multiply the 32-bit parts together then shift/add to get the result

Answer (score 6):

Generally you need 2*n bits to store the product of two n bit numbers (largest result is (2^n)^2 = 2^(2*n)), so my best idea is to split up the number into four 16-bit parts, multiply them one by one and add them together. 16 multiplications all in all, but error checking is trivial.

Comment: Error checking may be trivial but I suspect maintaining the carries would be a bit more complex.

Comment: Should be doable. The low part of the multiplication must be checked for overflow and carried into the high part, but that can't be avoided anyway.

Comment: Make sure you change your variables to positive and do unsigned multiplication, then change it to signed when done.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 'longlong.h' header file in the [GNU MP library](http://gmplib.org). I believe that a version of this header is also in the GNU C source. The macro: **smul_ppmm** is defined in terms of the unsigned double-word product: **umul_ppmm**. This gives you 32x32=>64 bit multiplication, which you might be able to use to implement 64x64=>128 bit multiplication.